# Python - How to modify text output using %s?

Tags: python, string

pretty straight forward to you guys but how do you modify the values output from the %s?

```
print "Successfully created the file: %s" % iFile + '.txt'
```

I have tried using ()'s, {}'s, but nothing is working?

iFile is the name of the file and I want it to be displayed with .txt at the end when its displayed.

Edit:

I get the output `Successfully created the file: <open file 'test', mode 'rb' at 0x14cef60>.txt`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`str.format(*args, **kwargs`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
"Successfully created the file: {0}.txt".format(iFile)
```

Example:

```
In [1]: iFile = "foo"

In [2]: "Successfully created the file: {0}.txt".format(iFile)
Out[2]: 'Successfully created the file: foo.txt'
```

**Edit**

Since you seem to have a file, not a file name, you could do this:

```
In [4]: iFile = open("/tmp/foo.txt", "w")

In [5]: "Successfully created the file: {0}.txt".format(iFile)
Out[5]: "Successfully created the file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/foo.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>.txt"

In [6]: "Successfully created the file: {0}.txt".format(iFile.name)
Out[6]: 'Successfully created the file: /tmp/foo.txt.txt'
```

Note that now the output is `foo.txt.txt` with a *double* extension. If you don't want this because the name of the file already is `foo.txt`, you don't should print the additional extension.

---

Using `%` is the old way to format strings. The current [Python tutorial explains `format` in detail](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're not passing it a string with the file name - you're passing it a file handle object, which is totally different. To get a name out of a file handle, use `iFile.name`.

```
print "Successfully created the file: %s" % iFile.name + '.txt'
```

That will print what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

you can try the following code. I tried in in Python shell and it works. I think you were just missing the parentheses.

```
print "Successfully created the file: %s.txt" % iFile
```

or

```
print "Successfully created the file: %s" % (iFile + '.txt')
```